# Can I reclaim control of the URL hash-fragment from Angular.Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

It's exact question as asked for AngularJS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268213/can-i-reclaim-control-of-the-url-hash-fragment-from-angularjs). I want to be able to do routing with a character thats not `#`, Is this possible with Angular.Dart?

Answer (score 0):

feel free to use html library with angular, it is comptiable

```
import 'dart:html';
main(){
    applicationFactory().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();
    document.querySelector("a").onClick.listen((MouseEvent e){
        String uri=(e.currentTarget as Element).attributes["href"];
        if(uri.contains("html")){
          window.location.replace(uri);
        }
    });
}
```

or better solution: use [_self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357759/angular-dart-disable-routing)